# Calculando uma data dentro do Model Django timedelta

Tags: python, django, model

Estou declarando uma função (data_prox_prog) para calcular uma data futura e armazenar no model, porém não está acontecendo o esperado.
Segue código:

```
class ProgressaoDocente(models.Model):
servidor = models.ForeignKey(Servidor, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
tipo_progressao = models.CharField(choices=const.TIPO_PROGRESSAO_DOC, max_length=1)
classe = models.CharField(choices=const.CLASSE_DOCENTE, max_length=1)
nivel = models.CharField(choices=const.NIVEL_DOCENTE, max_length=1)
data_progressao = models.DateField()
portaria = models.OneToOneField(Portaria, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
data_prox_progressao = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Progressão Docente'

def data_prox_prog(self):
    self.data_prox_prog = (self.data_progressao + timedelta(year=2))
    self.save()

def __str__(self):
    return "{} {}, {}/{}".format(self.servidor, self.tipo_progressao, self.classe, self.nivel)
```

Comment: Será útil para ajudar se colocares detalhes do erro que aparece, ou o resultado esperado e o resultado actual. O código dentro de `ProgressaoDocente` não deveria estar indentado?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver utilizando pre-save do Django Signals.
O esperado é que quando se instancia uma nova 'ProgressaoDocente', a partir da 'data_progressao', se defina o valor da 'data_prox_progressao', contando mais 2 anos da 'data_progressao', segue solução:

```
class ProgressaoDocente(models.Model):
    servidor = models.ForeignKey(Servidor, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    tipo_progressao = models.CharField(choices=const.TIPO_PROGRESSAO_DOC, 
    max_length=1)
    classe = models.CharField(choices=const.CLASSE_DOCENTE, max_length=1)
    nivel = models.CharField(choices=const.NIVEL_DOCENTE, max_length=1)
    data_progressao = models.DateField()
    portaria = models.OneToOneField(Portaria, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    data_prox_progressao = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Progressão Docente'

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {}, {}/{}".format(self.servidor, self.tipo_progressao, 
        self.classe, self.nivel)

@receiver(pre_save, sender=ProgressaoDocente)
def callback_progressao_docente(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    instance.data_prox_progressao = (instance.data_progressao + 
    relativedelta(years=+2))
```

Comment: Você pode também sobrescrever o método `save` e fazer essa atribuição antes de salvar. Usar signals (como o pre/post save) pode gerar algumas inconsitências no futuro (isso falando em casos onde a tendência do sistema seja crescer).